# Pine Script 4? "Undeclared identifier"

Tags: pine-script

I have received an Indacot in the language version=3, I would like to receive it in the version=4. Could someone help me or who may I contact?

Best thanks

```
//@version=3
//

study(title = "test", shorttitle = "test123", overlay = true)
 // pyramiding = 0, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value = 10, calc_on_every_tick=false)

// === INPUTS ===
useRes      = input(defval = true, title = "Use Alternate Resolution?")
intRes      = input(defval = 3,    title = "Multiplier for Alernate Resolution")
stratRes    = ismonthly? tostring(interval*intRes,"###M") : isweekly? tostring(interval*intRes,"###W") : isdaily?  tostring(interval*intRes,"###D") : isintraday ? tostring(interval*intRes,"####") : '60'
basisType   = input(defval = "SMMA", title = "MA Type: ", options=["SMA", "EMA", "DEMA", "TEMA", "WMA", "VWMA", "SMMA", "HullMA", "LSMA", "ALMA", "SSMA", "TMA"])
basisLen    = input(defval = 8, title = "MA Period", minval = 1)
offsetSigma = input(defval = 6, title = "Offset for LSMA / Sigma for ALMA", minval = 0)
offsetALMA  = input(defval = 0.85, title = "Offset for ALMA", minval = 0, step = 0.01)
scolor      = input(false, title="Show coloured Bars to indicate Trend?")
delayOffset = input(defval = 0, title = "Delay Open/Close MA (Forces Non-Repainting)", minval = 0, step = 1) 
tradeType   = input("BOTH", title="What trades should be taken : ", options=["LONG", "SHORT", "BOTH", "NONE"])
// === /INPUTS ===

// Constants colours that include fully non-transparent option.
green100 = #008000FF
lime100  = #00FF00FF
red100   = #FF0000FF
blue100  = #0000FFFF
aqua100  = #00FFFFFF
darkred100 = #8B0000FF
gray100 = #808080FF

// === BASE FUNCTIONS ===
// Returns MA input selection variant, default to SMA if blank or typo.
variant(type, src, len, offSig, offALMA) =>
    v1 = sma(src, len)                                                  // Simple
    v2 = ema(src, len)                                                  // Exponential
    v3 = 2 * v2 - ema(v2, len)                                          // Double Exponential
    v4 = 3 * (v2 - ema(v2, len)) + ema(ema(v2, len), len)               // Triple Exponential
    v5 = wma(src, len)                                                  // Weighted
    v6 = vwma(src, len)                                                 // Volume Weighted
    v7 = 0.0
    v7 := na(v7[1]) ? sma(src, len) : (v7[1] * (len - 1) + src) / len    // Smoothed
    v8 = wma(2 * wma(src, len / 2) - wma(src, len), round(sqrt(len)))   // Hull
    v9 = linreg(src, len, offSig)                                       // Least Squares
    v10 = alma(src, len, offALMA, offSig)                               // Arnaud Legoux
    v11 = sma(v1,len)                                                   // Triangular (extreme smooth)
    // SuperSmoother filter
    // © 2013  John F. Ehlers
    a1 = exp(-1.414*3.14159 / len)
    b1 = 2*a1*cos(1.414*3.14159 / len)
    c2 = b1
    c3 = (-a1)*a1
    c1 = 1 - c2 - c3
    v12 = 0.0
    v12 := c1*(src + nz(src[1])) / 2 + c2*nz(v12[1]) + c3*nz(v12[2])
    type=="EMA"?v2 : type=="DEMA"?v3 : type=="TEMA"?v4 : type=="WMA"?v5 : type=="VWMA"?v6 : type=="SMMA"?v7 : type=="HullMA"?v8 : type=="LSMA"?v9 : type=="ALMA"?v10 : type=="TMA"?v11: type=="SSMA"?v12: v1

// security wrapper for repeat calls
reso(exp, use, res) => use ? security(tickerid, res, exp, gaps=barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on) : exp

// === /BASE FUNCTIONS ===

// === SERIES SETUP ===
closeSeries     = variant(basisType, close[delayOffset], basisLen, offsetSigma, offsetALMA)
openSeries      = variant(basisType, open[delayOffset], basisLen, offsetSigma, offsetALMA)
// === /SERIES ===

// === PLOTTING ===

// Get Alternate resolution Series if selected.
closeSeriesAlt = reso(closeSeries, useRes, stratRes)
openSeriesAlt = reso(openSeries, useRes, stratRes)
//
trendColour = (closeSeriesAlt > openSeriesAlt) ? green : red
bcolour     = (closeSeries > openSeriesAlt) ? lime100 : red100
barcolor(scolor?bcolour:na, title = "Bar Colours")
closeP=plot(closeSeriesAlt, title = "Close Series", color = trendColour, linewidth = 2, style = line, transp = 20)
openP=plot(openSeriesAlt, title = "Open Series", color = trendColour, linewidth = 2, style = line, transp = 20)
fill(closeP,openP,color=trendColour,transp=80)

// === /PLOTTING ===
//

//
// === ALERT conditions
xlong       = crossover(closeSeriesAlt, openSeriesAlt)
alertcondition(xlong, title="xlong signal", message="xlong Alert")
xshort      = crossunder(closeSeriesAlt, openSeriesAlt)
alertcondition(xshort, title="xshort signal", message="xshort Alert")
longCond    = xlong   // alternative: longCond[1]? false : (xlong or xlong[1]) and close>closeSeriesAlt and close>=open
alertcondition(longCond, title="Go LONG signal", message="go long")
shortCond   = xshort  // alternative: shortCond[1]? false : (xshort or xshort[1]) and close<closeSeriesAlt and close<=open
alertcondition(shortCond, title="Go SHORT", message="Go Short")

// === /ALERT conditions.

// === STRATEGY ===
// stop loss
slPoints    = input(defval = 0, title = "Initial Stop Loss Points (zero to disable)", minval = 0)
tpPoints    = input(defval = 0, title = "Initial Target Profit Points (zero for disable)", minval = 0)
// Include bar limiting algorithm
ebar            = input(defval = 10000, title="Number of Bars for Back Testing", minval=0)
dummy           = input(false,        title="- SET to ZERO for Daily or Longer Timeframes" )
//
// Calculate how many mars since last bar
tdays       = (timenow-time)/60000.0  // number of minutes since last bar
tdays       := ismonthly? tdays/1440.0/5.0/4.3/interval : isweekly? tdays/1440.0/5.0/interval : isdaily? tdays/1440.0/interval : tdays/interval // number of bars since last bar
//
//set up exit parameters
TP = tpPoints>0?tpPoints:na
SL = slPoints>0?slPoints:na

// Make sure we are within the bar range, Set up entries and exit conditions
//longCond ((ebar==0 or tdays<=ebar) and tradeType!="NONE")
//alertcondition(crossunder, title="long signal", message="long Signal alert")

//shortcond ((ebar==0 or tdays<ebar) and tradeType!"NONE")
//alertcondition(crossover, title="Short signal", message="Short signal Alert")
  // strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, when=longCond==true and tradeType!="SHORT")
 //trategy.entry("long", strategy.long, when=longCond==true and tradeType!="SHORT")
  //  strategy.entry("short", strategy.short, when=shortCond==true and tradeType!="LONG")
  //  strategy.close("long", when = shortCond==true and tradeType=="LONG")
 //   strategy.close("short", when = longCond==true and tradeType=="SHORT")
 //   strategy.exit("XL", from_entry = "long", profit = TP, loss = SL)
  //  strategy.exit("XS", from_entry = "short", profit = TP, loss = SL)

// === /STRATEGY ===
// eof
```

Answer (score 0):

the pine editor is equipped with a conversion tool and works to convert to a later version on your script. Notice "Convert to v4".

[image: Here is a picture of where to find it in your editor]